# Help identifying ground screw?

Tags: grounding

I’m installing a ceiling fan and my electrical box doesn’t have a ground wire. Are either of the screws in the picture a ground screw?
[image]

Comment: If the letters under the cable are GND that is where ground screw should be/go.  If the box is not grounded already, a ground screw is not much sense for safety, since it does nothing.  Boxes like that are grounded by a ground wire in the cable or by metal conduit.

Comment: simple test, use multimeter and check between the hot and screws. If you see 120 V it is grounded

Answer (score 5):

None of the screws shown are good for attaching a ground wire. You'll need a 10-32 ground screw and it will fit into one of the smaller holes in the box. You'll need to verify that the box is grounded hopefully by the BX metallic cable. Use your multi meter and test from black to box to see if you get approximately 120V. If you do,  the box is grounded and attach your fan green wire to the ground screw. If the box isn't grounded, just cap the ground with a wire nut.

Now the bad news. It doesn't look like this ceiling box is rated for a ceiling fan so you'll need to change it out to a box that is rated for one. Check the inside on the box to see if there's printing that says it's rated.

Comment: Good catch on the ceiling fan problem, which is more important.

Comment: There’s no printing saying it’s rated for a fan. That means it’s not?

Comment: @Julian  It is not rated for a fan.  Not enough support from the framing or from the two screws into the box.